# Show wait cursor on button click before executing synchronous ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to change the cursor to a wait cursor after the users clicks on a button.
Therefor i add the class "wait" to the body which has the follwing logic: `cursor: wait !important;`

Please take a look at the Button Event Handler below. As you can see, right after i add the class "wait" to body, i call a function which executes an synchronous ajax request.

This request will delete about 300 files on the server and then reloads the page afterwards.

```
<div id='mybutton'>Button</div>
```

**Button Event Handler**

```
$("div#mybutton").click(function(){

    $("body").addClass("wait");
    delete_all();
});
```

**CSS**

```
body.wait, body.wait *{
    cursor: wait !important;   
}
```

**delete_all()**

```
function delete_all() {
...

    list.each(function(){
    ...
        $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: { cmd: "delete_files", ... },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.warn(response);
        }});
    ...
    });

    //Reload the page
    window.location.reload();
...
}
```

**Problem**: The Cursor never changes to a waiting cursor because of the synchronous ajax request, if i change `async` to true then it works, but i need it to be synchronous.

Is there a workaround or another solution for me, other then setting `async` to true?

Comment: Please don't use `async: false`. It's *terrible* practice. There's a reason you get warnings in the console when you use it.

Comment: Why do you need to use a synchronous call?

Comment: To prevent the user interacting with the website.

Comment: Then use an overlay. `async: false` locks the browser making it look like it has hung to the user. Also reloading the page straight after making the AJAX requests seems entirely redundant. Either get the data you need through those AJAX requests and dynamically update the DOM, or use a standard form submission to reload the page, not both

Comment: Backing @RoryMcCrossan on the reloading. its is redundant and not exactly useful.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `window.location.reload()` will reload your page and the class you set using  `$("body").addClass("wait");` will be lost. Instead, remove that class in your success and error and make sure you are using async:true.

Comment: My question is how to solve this with `async: false`...
Read my last sentence please: "Is there a workaround or another solution for me, other then setting `async` to true?"

Comment: It wont make sense because if you make it async: true it will not wait for the success or error response and straightway execute window.location.reload and there for the "wait" does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a flag like this:
On the button click:

```
loading = true;
runWaitingCursor();
```

And here is the runWaitingCursor function:

```
runWaitingCursor = function(){
    if(loading == true){
        $("body").addClass("wait");
    }else{
        $("body").removeClass("wait");
    }

}
```

and on ajax success run:

```
loading = false;
runWaitingCursor();
```

Comment: Thats basically what i am already doing. I tried it with your exact code, but the mouse cursor does not change during the synchronous axaj request.

Comment: maybe you don't see that because you are working on the localhost and it's too fast to see?
try to keep the loading value as true and check what happens.

Comment: No the webserver is running on an odroid, it does not work even though loading is always true.

Comment: A little late to this conversation, but the cursor: wait; css doesn't visually take effect because the browser CHOOSES to not re-render the DOM before it starts your sync AJAX call. The style is applied, but the DOM does not re-render because most modern browser rendering engines wait until the JavaScript thread is idle before the DOM is updated. A quick fix for this behavior is to make the css class change via JavaScript, then put your long-running code behind a setTimeout delay, usually about 20ms.

Answer (score -1):

A little late to this conversation, but the `cursor: wait;` css doesn't *visually* take effect because the browser CHOOSES to not re-render the DOM before it starts your sync AJAX call. Basically, the style is applied, but the DOM does not re-render because most modern browser rendering engines wait until the JavaScript thread is idle before the DOM is updated.

A quick fix for this behavior is to make the css class change via JavaScript, then put your long-running code behind a setTimeout delay, usually about 20ms.